# Finding the difference of values in a series in pandas based on another time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a financial time series in pandas and a time series 'Position' which takes value 1 when the trend is positive, otherwise is -1. The Position series alternates constantly 1 and -1. Is there a function or a smart way to find the difference between the start and the end of a positive period? More specifically, I want to sum all the deltas, but in order to do so I'm struggling to find a way to determine where the trend starts and where it ends. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume, you have a dataframe like this:

```
         date  value
0  2020-11-12     10
1  2020-11-13     12
2  2020-11-14     15
3  2020-11-15     17
4  2020-11-16     17
5  2020-11-17     11
6  2020-11-18     12
7  2020-11-19      9
8  2020-11-20      7
```

and you want to calculate the difference between the start and end value of the ascending periods, Then you get this result:

```
          start_date  first_value  last_value  difference
trend_no                                                 
1         2020-11-12           10          17           7
2         2020-11-17           11          12           1
```

By executing the following code:

```
# work out the trend of the series
df['difference']= df['value'] - df['value'].shift(1).fillna(0)
df['trend']= np.sign(df['difference'])

# work out the start and end of an ascending series
df['start_ascend']= (df['trend'].shift(-1) > df['trend']).astype('bool')
df.loc[0, 'start_ascend']= True
df['end_ascend']= (df['trend'].shift(-1) < df['trend']).astype('bool')

# assign a number to the ascending trends
# note, that the trends are not yet limited correctly
df['trend_no']= df['start_ascend'].cumsum()

# now work out the borders of the ascending trends
# all records that belong to an ascending trend
# will have df['keep_mask'] == True
df['keep_mask']= np.nan
indexer= df['end_ascend'].shift(1).fillna(False) 
df.loc[indexer, 'keep_mask']= 0.0
df.loc[df['start_ascend'], 'keep_mask']= 1.0
df['keep_mask']= df['keep_mask'].fillna(method='ffill').astype('bool')

# now do the final aggregation
df_res= df[df['keep_mask']].groupby(df['trend_no']).agg(start_date=('date', 'first'), first_value=('value', 'first'), last_value=('value', 'last'))
df_res['difference']= df_res['last_value'] - df_res['first_value']
df_res
```

If you want to understand, what the steps above actually did, you can look at the dataframe:

```
         date  value  trend  start_ascend  end_ascend  trend_no  keep_mask
0  2020-11-12     10    1.0          True       False         1       True
1  2020-11-13     12    1.0         False       False         1       True
2  2020-11-14     15    1.0         False       False         1       True
3  2020-11-15     17    1.0         False        True         1       True
4  2020-11-16     17    0.0         False        True         1      False
5  2020-11-17     11   -1.0          True       False         2       True
6  2020-11-18     12    1.0         False        True         2       True
7  2020-11-19      9   -1.0         False       False         2      False
8  2020-11-20      7   -1.0         False       False         2      False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sum the previous and current position value, you could look for where it's 0, which would be a spot that the trend flipped.

Like this:

```
trend_flipped = df["Trend"] + df["Trend"].shift() == 0
df[trend_flipped]
```